# Conversion from string "select CustName from tblCustMst " to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, vb.net

The below code giving Conversion exception in 2nd statement.

```
 Dim query As String = "select CustName from tblCustMst " & "where PlantId=@PlantId"
 cmd.CommandType = query
```

Comment: It gives error in 2nd statement

Comment: you don't assign your query to CommandType.  CommandType is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `cmd.CommandText`.
Try this:

```
Dim query As String = "select CustName from tblCustMst " & "where PlantId=@PlantId"
cmd.CommandText= query
```

good luck.

Comment: the issue is when he assigns the query to CommandType, changing to CommandText I bet fixes his issue